How to package the pyspark application using the pipenv?
I have developed a pyspark application using many packages like Pandas, NumPy, mongo, etc. I am required to package the application and deploy it to the EMR cluster.
I have referred to Spark documentation but haven't found a solution :
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html?source=post_page-----2eb2a27523a3--------------------------------
